# Cheapest subgraph of a tree that contains any k vertices?

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming

Given a tree, I want to find the cost of the cheapest connected subgraph of it, which contains a particular node $v$, and $k-1$ other edges.

Each vertex has exactly 1 or 3 children.

My thought was to use dynamic programming - root the tree at $v$, then then treating each vertex as a subtree, calculate the cost of the cheapest subgraph starting at that vertex which contains $0$ ... $k-1$ other edges. Let these costs be $c_0...c_{k-1}$ and let $d_1 = c_1 - c_0 ...$. Then for a vertex, provided the $d_i$s have been calculated for its children, select vertices greedily from its children until $k$ vertices are obtained.

I've gotten this far, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: And what's your question? You stated a problem and a possible solution to be explored, but no question.

Comment: Essentially, I'm asking if I'm going in the right direction. I'd appreciate a hint.